# AngularJS +how to wait for task to finish before running next task

Tags: angularjs

I have still problems with my database, but I found out, that the problems come from the fact, that opening the database takes some time, but the app is not waiting till this task has finished.

Is there a way to make angular wait till the database is opened correctly before it starts the next task?

Thanks,
Christian.

---

**Update: 2016-08-08 - 03:13 pm**

Thanks for all the answers. As I can see, my first idea with promises ($q) was right, but:

My app has an app.js, which is my main file. It only calls the InitDB. This should open the database. Then it should call the CreateTables, this creates the table, if it doensn't exist.

The rest of my app is splitted in 4 pages (templates). Every page has it's own controller.

So the idea was to init the db, to create the table, and then work with the database, but used over different controllers.

This won't work, because I would always need to put all of my stuff in the .then() of my initDB in the app.js???

This is my first AngularJS app, maybe this is the reason why I do a lot of mistakes...

Thanks,
Christian.

Comment: You could work with a promise, and resolve it when database is up: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the core concepts of Angular is working with services/factories. There is ample documentation and blogs about how these work and how to use them, but the basic idea is that these are singleton "controllers" that handle shared data and methods across your entire application. Used in combination with promises, you can easily create a service that will manage communications with your database.

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .service('DBService', DBService)
  .controller('Ctrl1', Ctrl1)
  .controller('Ctrl2', Ctrl2)
  .controller('Ctrl3', Ctrl3)
  .controller('Ctrl4', Ctrl4);

DBService.$inject = ['$q'];
function DBService($q) {
  var DBService = this;
  var DBServiceDeferred = $q.defer();
  DBService.ready = DBServiceDeferred.promise;

  // a service is only initialized once, so this will only ever be run once
  (function() {
    init();
  })();

  function init() {
    // you can use promise chaining to control order of events
    // the chain will halt if any function is rejected
    initDB()
    .then(createTablesUnlessExist)
    .then(setDbReady);
  }

  function initDB() { 
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    // simulate async db initialization
    $timeout(function() {
      deferred.resolve();
      // or reject if there is an error
      // deferred.reject();
    }, 5000);
    return deferred.promise;
  };

  function createTablesUnlessExist() {
    //create tables if needed (only happens once)
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    // simulate async table creation
    $timeout(function() {
      deferred.resolve();
      // or reject if there is an error
      // deferred.reject();
    }, 5000);
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  function setDbReady() {
    DBServiceDeferred.resolve();
  }
}
```

Now you have your DB setup and you don't have to worry about it anymore. You can access the DB from any controller using the service. None of the queries will run until the DB has been initialized and the tables have been created.

```
Ctrl1.$inject = ['DBService', '$q'];
function Ctrl1(DBService, $q) {
  $q.when(DBService.ready).then(function() {
    DBService.conn.query("Select something");
  });
}
Ctrl2.$inject = ['DBService', '$q'];
function Ctrl2(DBService, $q) {
  $q.when(DBService.ready).then(function() {
    DBService.conn.query("Select something");
  });
}
Ctrl3.$inject = ['DBService', '$q'];
function Ctrl3(DBService, $q) {
  $q.when(DBService.ready).then(function() {
    DBService.conn.query("Select something");
  });
}
Ctrl4.$inject = ['DBService', '$q'];
function Ctrl4(DBService, $q) {
  $q.when(DBService.ready).then(function() {
    DBService.conn.query("Select something");
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi JoelCDoyle, this is one of the intrestings answers I read. Thank you! But now I have some other questions: 1. In your factory you call the init() function directly. Is this safe? This would mean, that the thing is inizializing itself when the app starts? How do you close it, when the app is closed? 2. I thought that I had to put all the database logic (CRUD) in the factory, but you call it from the controllers? Is this just for the quick example, or is this best practices? 3. In the controller, if the DBService would not be ready, will the tasks wait or produce an error? Infinite loop?

Comment: Hi again. I completely reworte my factory with all of your hints, but I get always an error, when it comes to the setDbReady() function. Instead of DBService, I took PersistenceService. So when I do the PersistenceService.ready.resolve(); I get the error TypeError: PersistenceService.ready.resolve is not a function ... Any idea? Thanks, Christian.

Comment: You are correct, you don't really want to make queries from within the controllers, that was just for demonstration purposes. You would want to create methods in your service that the controllers can call to make queries. There is a mistake in my code. Here is a plunker with the corrected, working code. Watch the console to see the order of operations: https://plnkr.co/edit/AWtM0lF2491fFUtqQYaz?p=preview

Comment: As far as closing the connection, you could add a method to the service that closes the connection. Yes the init method is called when the service is instantiated. Nothing unsafe or abnormal about that, but you can do what ever you want really. You can close it just as easily as you opened it, by adding a close method to the service. The tasks will be performed in the order you specify, period. If there is an error in one task, all other tasks will be cancelled. You can see this behavior yourself by "reject()"ing the deferred instead of resolving it at any point along the way.

Comment: Hi JoelCDoyle. Thank's for all of your hints and your work. I think, I have still an understanding problem: This system only waits for the tasks, it doesn't care, if they worked or not? Because if I produce on purpose an error with my database, all tasks are done step by step.

Comment: To halt the promise chain, call reject on the deferred, instead of resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Angular provides a service $q. A service that helps you run functions asynchronously, and use their return values (or exceptions) when they are done processing. Please refer the documentation   [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)  for the same.
$q basically revolves around the concepts of promises. Promises in AngularJS are provided by the built-in $q service.

Answer (score 0):

Write a method that check if connection is established or not...which returns true or false.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, httpq) {
    http.get('server call method')
      .then(function(data) {
        if(data.conn==true)
       // do what u want
      //write other calls
      })
      .catch(function(data, status) {
        console.error('error', response.status, response.data);
      })

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use $q library

example:

```
app.service("githubService", function ($http, $q) {
var deferred = $q.defer();

this.getAccount = function () {
    return $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/haroldrv')
        .then(function (response) {
            // promise is fulfilled
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
            // promise is returned
            return deferred.promise;
        }, function (response) {
            // the following line rejects the promise 
            deferred.reject(response);
            // promise is returned
            return deferred.promise;
        })
    ;
};
```

});

using above service:

```
app.controller("promiseController", function ($scope, $q, githubService) {
githubService.getAccount()
    .then(
        function (result) {
            // promise was fullfilled (regardless of outcome)
            // checks for information will be peformed here
            $scope.account = result;
        },
        function (error) {
            // handle errors here
            console.log(error.statusText);
        }
    );
```

});